# Assign title atribute based on <p> tag content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

That's it... Having a lot of `p` tags with a class (let's say `.text`), I need to add the [title](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) attribute with the text of the tag. So, if I have this:

```
<p> Hello, world </p>
```

It'll give me this

```
<p title="Hello, world"> Hello, world </p>
```

Comment: (OT) next time add to your Questions: *"So far I have tried this: `code snippet` but id did not worked cause...etc."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/prop/#computed-prop-values

Access the desired Element property and inside it's **callback** function simply `return` the desired value from a Method like `return $(this).text();`

```js
$("p").prop("title", function(){ // Every "p" "title", set to:
    return $(this).text();       // it's text value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Hello, world</p>
<p>StackOverflow</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript,you can try

> document.getElementById('myptag').setAttribute('title','Hello,world');
>   and set id="myptag" in html p tag.

If you use jquery,you need to add jquery.js and try

> $(document).ready(function() {
>           $("p").attr('title','hello,world');
>        });

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
$("p").attr("title","Hello, world");
```

OR

```
$("p").prop("title","Hello, world");
```